# The folder “Icons.xcassets” doesn’t exist when opening xCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset

I have a project that has a number of targets and now I am getting the error `The folder “Icons.xcassets” doesn’t exist.` in two popups when I open the project or move around targets.  What would be causing this?

Comment: Remove Icons.xcassets reference from Xcode, then remove every line of your xxx.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj; finally, add your Icons.xcassets back to your project again. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project -> Targets -> Select General Tab -> Go to section App Icons and Launch images -> Select Don't use asset catalogue against App Icons Source.

Doing so silenced this warning in my case. [See the image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le8d6.png)